# How to estimate the mean and variance of a Gaussian distribution variable?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, variance, mean

I have two variables 2X and 0.5Y, both are independent and follows Gaussian distribution. How to estimate their mean and variance analytically? I want to know their individual mean and variance, then I want to add them.

Comment: This question is unclear. It is unclear whether you have some samplea and want to estimate or whether you know variance and mean of X and Y and want to analytically derive variance of Z=2X and W=0.5Y. Also if this is homework remember to tag it accordingly.

Comment: no its not a homework, I need this for my research work. I have data set name X, which can be distributed as Gaussian with mean µ and variance σ. but in my equation, my variable has a coefficient, like 2X. I need to add 2X with .5Y. If it only X, then I know, the mean and variance is µ and σ respectively. but i am in trouble with this coefficient. I don't know the variance and mean of this data. I want to know how can I mathematically derive mean and variance? How can I add them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum of normal independent random variables with coefficients](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/344859/sum-of-normal-independent-random-variables-with-coefficients)

Answer (score 1):

Let $z = ax$ and $w=by$ with $a$ and $b$ known constants and $x\sim \mathcal N(\mu_x,\sigma_x^2)$ and $y\sim\mathcal N(\mu_y,\sigma_y^2)$ then

$$v = z + w = ax + by$$ is sum of two independent normally distributed variables and hence will be normal.

The mean $\mu_v = \mathbb E[v] = a\mu_x + b \mu_y$ and

The variance $\sigma^2_v = a^2 \sigma_x^2 + b^2\sigma_y^2$
since covariance part is 0 from the assumption of independence.

Comment: yes, thank you so much, But I want to know, How can I know derive mathematically mean and variance by using PDF of gaussian? my mean can be 2µ and variance can be 2σ. How can I know that?

Comment: Like using Integration or differentiation of PDF of Gaussian

Comment: Well in that case look up sum of random normals on wiki theres a proof using moment generating function or if you prefer proof by pdf just read the proof there using convolutions.